# Login and upload file using Python 'flask' app

Tags: python, flask

I Have created a flask app which need to upload files to server and also need to take login detail on same html form .

I am able to upload file to destination folder , but credential part is not getting fetched/submit to form and unable to get this in flask app for further processing .

i need to do some operation on this file based on user credentials ( i know credential are plain text )

**Html form :-**

```
<form action="/import" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

  <p>User name <input name="username" type="text" /></p>
<p>User password: <input name="psw" type="password" /></p>

<p><input name="file" type="file" /> <input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>

</form>
```

**Flask Application code :-**

```
    from flask import Flask, render_template, request
    from werkzeug import secure_filename
    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/import')
    def import_form():
       return render_template('import.html')

    @app.route('/import', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
    def import_form():
       if request.method == 'POST':
          username = request.args.get('username')
          psw = request.args.get('psw')
          psw = str(psw)
          username=str(username)
          f = request.files['file']
          f.save(secure_filename(f.filename))
          fname = f.filename

          cmd = ('sh myscript.sh -u '+username+' -p '+psw+' -src '+fname)  # command to pass parameter as user name password and file name in directory 

          p = subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
              stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
          return out    
if __name__ == '__main__':
       app.run(debug = True)
```

output of this come as below ( user name and password value come as blank/none )

**sh myscript.sh -u *none* -p *none* -src xyz.file**

I want to get user name password and file upload on same page then process this request under a shell script t o return output of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got solution for this issue by one of my colleagues help

need to use as below to get argument enter on screen form .

```
username = request.form['username']
psw = reques.form['psw']
```